# Reading a text file with BOLT in unity

Tags: unity

I assume as the Bolt is an asset for Unity then I could ask my question about Bolt here.
I couldn't find any tutorial about how to read a file in Bolt?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar with BOLT, could you explain what it is? Also, if you are using unity, why would you try to read a file using BOLT and not unity itself?

Comment: For explanation:
Bolt is a node based visual scripting tool, which explains why OP doesn't read the file via C#.